CORS Issue in Nginx with FastAPI: Works with `*` but Fails with Specific Domains
I'm facing a CORS issue while configuring my FastAPI application behind an Nginx reverse proxy. The setup works fine when I set Access-Control-Allow-Origin to *. However, when I replace * with specific domains, I get a CORS error in the browser:
Here is my Nginx configuration:
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name backend.example.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/backend.example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/backend.example.com/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

    location /neurotalk/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8443;  # Proxying to Uvicorn
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

        # CORS headers
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'https://frontend.example.com';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Authorization, Content-Type';

        # Additional settings
        proxy_read_timeout 90;
        proxy_connect_timeout 90;
        proxy_redirect off;

        # Disable buffering for streaming responses
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_request_buffering off;
    }
}

In my FastAPI application, I have also added CORS middleware like this:
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware

app = FastAPI()

origins = [
    "https://frontend.example.com",
]

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=origins,
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)

When I set add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' in Nginx, everything works fine. But when I replace it with the specific domain (https://frontend.example.com), the CORS error appears in the browser.
I've tried the following:

Double-checked the domain name spelling.
Cleared the browser cache.
Restarted Nginx and the FastAPI application.
Could someone help me understand why this configuration works with * but fails with a specific domain?


It seems like you’re facing a CORS issue when specifying a particular domain in your Nginx configuration for your FastAPI application. Your setup works with a wildcard (*) but fails with a specific domain.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.


Browsers send a preflight request (an OPTIONS request) before the actual request when dealing with CORS. Ensure that your Nginx configuration handles these preflight requests properly.
Ensure that CORS headers are not being set twice. By having Nginx and FastAPI both set CORS headers, there might be a conflict. In some cases, it might be best to have Nginx handle CORS for simplicity.
Ensure the order of your Nginx directives is correct. Specifically, handle the OPTIONS method before other methods.
Clear Browser Cache

